# How to create a field whose text changes in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am just starting with android. This is what i want to make:
[image: What i want to make]

Now when you click on From, a new screen would open where you can select places and once you select you will get back to this screen where instead of "Bangalore" it would be the place you selected.

What kind of a field is this ? Text field ?
Also if i want to add any effect like when you click on it its color changes, how would i go about it ? Any tutorials or documentation i can check out for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will probably want to use [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

You can change the text it displays by using [SetText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), and you can change the text color by using [SetTextColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The whole white area is clickable, can i make it so with textview that anywhere i touch the new dialog opens up and only text in certain small space changes ? ( "bangalore" here )

Comment: Your textview will probably be encapsulated inside of a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) or a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). In this case, that layout would represent the entire white area, so you could make that layout clickable, and using an OnClickListener, you can run code when that layout is clicked. Here's a tutorial for OnClickListener: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/view/onclicklistener/android-onclicklistener-example/

Answer (score 0):

You need a `TextView` to display text, but if you want to display an image, text and be able to interact with that, then `Button` or `ImageButton` is what you need.

Your question is too broad, so I encourage you to start doing some tutorials. To implement all that stuff you'll need to learn about layouts and activities, dialogs, listviews, ... Basic Android, but it needs a minimum of experience.